# Suffixes interchangeability

Tags: sufijos

Looks like "*-(c)ito*, *-(c)ita*" and "*-(c)illo*, *-(c)illa*" are quite interchangeable (though the last ones are less common). What are the differences between them? What about other suffixes whithing the same groups(*-(c)ito*, *-(c)illo*, *-zuelo*, *-(c)ín*, *-(c)iño***;** *-ote*, *-ón*, *-azo***;** *-aco*, *-ajo*, *-ote*, *-ucho*)?

Which feature does each of them have? Or do they mostly depend on regional traditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of them depend on regional variations (*-iño* for example is something that you would hear in the north of Spain, influenced by Galician speakers).

Other suffixes may contain different inflections (-illo may contain an emotional inflection).

> Diner**ito** vs diner**illo**
>
> Hombrec**ito** vs hombre**cillo**

Also -illo may depict things that are smaller than -ito (cucharita vs. cucharilla) but there is not a definitive rule about this.

[-zuelo](http://www.gramaticas.net/2011/02/ejemplos-sufijo-zuelo-zuela.html) may also contain emotional (pejorative) connotations.

The differences and connotations between them may be so fuzzy that the context would give you more information than the suffix itself and is not possible to get a proper, definitive list of the variations of significance and connotations of each one of the suffixes.

-illo and -cillo may be less common due to regional differences. Some Spanish dialects may be less prone to use certain suffixes (making even more difficult to get a definitive list of the exact connotation of a diminutive or its divergence/variance from others).

Comment: Other regional variations are "-ico" (very used in Navarra) and "-uco" (in Cantabria)

Answer (score 2):

This image shows the common diminutive suffixes used in different regions of Spain (and Portugal):

[image: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutivo]

#### By Region:

- **-ito, -ita**: most common suffix used by Spanish speakers
- **-ico, -ica**: eastern Spain: Andalucía Oriental, La Mancha, Aragón, Navarra, La Rioja, Región de Murcia, Comunidad Valenciana occidental

  - Also used (as opposed to *-ito*) in Venezuela, Cuba, República Dominicana, Colombia, Costa Rica for words  whose final syllable starts with *-t*.
- **-illo, -illa**: used mainly in Spain (especially Andalucía). Mostly interchangeable with *-ito*. Can be `affectionate` or `pejorative.`
- **-ete, -eta**: of catalán/valenciano/aragonés origin. Also used in La Mancha and murciano. In a non-Catalan context is mostly `pejorative`.
- **-ín, -ina**: especially Asturias and Región Leonesa. More emphatic than *-ito, -ita*. `Affectionate`
- **-ino, -ina**: Extremadura
- **-uco, -uca**: Cantabria. In rural areas also **-ucu**. In the rest of Spain, when used, this is mostly a `pejorative` suffix.

#### Less common suffixes

- **-ajo, -aja**: Used in La Mancha and murciano.
- **-ejo, -eja**: La Mancha.
- **-ujo, -uja**: Murciano.
- **-icho/-iche, -icha**: Murciano.
- **-iquio, -iquia**: Murciano and Valencia. Variant of *-ico, -ica*.
- **-ucho, -ucha**: Venezuela. Can be `pejorative`

There are others, but these are even less common (see the links at the bottom).

Augmentative suffixes are almost always pejorative, e.g. **-ón, -ona, -ote, -ota, -azo, -aza** etc.

As Diego says, however, the specific meaning is often context-specific, due to regionalisms, different productivity of different suffixes, some words having lexicalised the suffix etc.

---

- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aumentativo
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutivo
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Spanish/Diminutives
- [*"Morfofonología de la formación de diminutivos en español: ¿reglas morfológicas o restricciones fonológicas?"*](http://www.academia.edu/5888100/_Morfofonolog%C3%ADa_de_la_formaci%C3%B3n_de_diminutivos_en_espa%C3%B1ol_reglas_morfol%C3%B3gicas_o_restricciones_fonol%C3%B3gicas_en_A._F%C3%A1bregas_et_alii_eds._Los_l%C3%ADmites_de_la_Morfolog%C3%ADa._Estudios_ofrecidos_a_Soledad_Varela_Ortega_Madrid_UAM_2012_p%C3%A1gs._55-78_en_colaboraci%C3%B3n_con_Th%C3%A9ophile_Ambadiang_), Théophile Ambadiang, Bruno Camus Bergareche